# need to change file path with its id in database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a code which is uploading file and saving its path in database. Now i want to change its path to its corresponding id with which it is saving in database i.e i have uploaded an image and its id is '4' in database and its file path should also be 4. and if i upload an other image and if its id is 5 then in its file path column there should also be 5 and so on. I have searched for a while but i'm not able to find the proper answer. Kindly help me here.
Here is my code

directory-image.php

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>image in directory</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" action="directory-imagedatabase.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>Choose File to Upload:</label><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="id" />

    <input type="file" name="uploadimage" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" id="upload" />

    </form>
    </body> 
    </html>

directory-imagedatabase.php

    <?php
    $target_Folder = 'images/';

    $uid = $_POST['id'];


    $target_Path = $target_Folder.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

    $savepath = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

        $file_name = $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];

        if(file_exists('officework/php-startup/images/'.$file_name))
    {
        echo "That File Already Exisit";
        }
        else
        {

            // Database
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sal123","test"); //Change it if required

    //Check Connection
            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to database" .     mysqli_connect_errno();
            }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO directoryimage (id,image, image_name) 
    VALUES ('','$target_Folder$file_name','$file_name') ";         
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            echo "1 record added successfully in the database";
            echo '<br />';
            mysqli_close($con);

            // Move the file into UPLOAD folder

            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'],     $target_Path );

            echo "File Uploaded <br />";
            echo 'File Successfully Uploaded to:&nbsp;' . $target_Path;
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'File Name:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];
            echo'<br />';
            echo 'File Type:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['type'];
            echo'<br />';
            echo 'File Size:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['size'];

        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You want the file to be renamed so that it's name is the same is the id field?

Comment: You need a two step approach, obviously, since you _first_ need to create the ID with an `INSERT` statement, then fetch that ID using the `last_insert_id` feature. Then you can save the file using that ID and `UPDATE` the created entry.

Comment: no right now i want to change the file path which is saved in database with its id field @e4c5

Comment: sorry that statement isn't clear either

Comment: @e4c5 ok let me explain a bit. In my database i have 3 fields Id, image-name and filepath. after uploading a file it gets save in my directory and in file path filed in database its shows me this " images/1509682_688540691291466_4951349513501967578_n.jpg "  i need to replace it its id.jpg

Comment: @arkascha so you get my point  right? i have a id variable and it is auto incremented do i need to insert id manually?

Comment: So this is about some cleanup in an existing system, not to modify the upload implementation? In that case the answer is obvious: you iterate over all existing entries you got using a `SELECT` query, then move the existing files from the path you read from the database to a new location based on the ID you also read and finally `UPDATE` each record with that new path. What is your question with that? What is your issue here? Sounds pretty straight forward to me...

Comment: well this is some logic! i asked it because i need to be sure that you got my point clear as a fellow member said he didn't get my point clear

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the record's insert ID `$id = mysqli_insert_id($con)` after the `INSERT`
2. Get file extension: `$ext = preg_replace("/\.(gif|jpg|etc)$/", ".$1", $file_name);`
3. Rename the file with [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) `rename("$target_Folder$file_name", $id . $ext);`
4. Update the record with something like `$sql = "UPDATE directoryimage SET image = CONCAT('{$target_Folder}', id, '{$ext}') WHERE id = $id";`

Comment: @leonardochallis sir thankyou so much for you help but im getting these two warning ( Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in  ) and ( rename(images/12895293_1099151520146863_391821049_n.jpg,41): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)  ) here and still the file path is not being replaced with its id

Comment: My bad, a small type (missed comma) that is fixed. It's important that you understand what's going on with the code though, this is a suggestion on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: i have removed the error. and now there is no error but still that filepath column is not replaced with its id

Comment: and yes i'm understand quite alot with the logic you used

Comment: I suggest you add some debug output (like `var_dump`) on each line you've changed so you can see where the issue is. Maybe update the code in your original question so we can see exactly what your code now does